# Creating a 'basket' for a stock management program?

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access, relational-database

When you buy things online, you add them to your basket and when you've done adding things to your basket, you create an order. Essentially, I am trying to think of the best way to allow multiple items to be put into one order. This is more a case of not knowing how to store the data in a database in Access. I can't figure out what the fields should be called. My current attempt is this:

```
tblOrders
OrderID (Primary Key)
CustomerID (Foreign Key)
OrderDetailsID


tblOrderDetails
OrderDetailsID
PartID (Foreign Key)
Quantity
```

[This](http://bit.ly/HoRJfU) is an image of the first table with example data and [this](http://bit.ly/HoRX6I) is an example of the second table. It's very likely that I've missed something blindingly obvious.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd structure it like this:

```
OrderHeader
  ID (Primary Key)
  CustomerID (Foreign Key)

OrderDetail
  ID (Primary Key)
  OrderHeaderID (Foreign Key)
  PartID (Foreign Key)
  Quantity
```

- Read up on [*Hungarian Notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) as a naming convention, and consider dropping your `tbl` prefixes. This is just a preference you may choose to ignore.
- `OrderDetailID` on the `OrderHeader` won't work because you won't be able to produce the necessary `1:M` relationship where an order can have multiple detail lines.
- Use surrogate `ID` fields for your primary keys. They make working with `JOIN` a lot easier. If you want to enforce a condition that an order can only use a part **once**, then you should do so with a unique database constraint on columns `OrderHeaderID` and `PartID`.

Here's a sample query for your comment...

```
SELECT H.ID OrderID, D.PartID, D.Quantity
FROM OrderHeader AS H INNER JOIN
     OrderDetail AS D ON H.ID = D.OrderHeaderID
WHERE H.ID = 1234;
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand this and thanks for the interesting read on Hungarian Notation! Me being a somewhat beginner at programming, this might sound silly, but with your structure above, would I then use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)? I can see that this would be the solution, but I am having problems visualising it. 

Using your example with the link above would mean that our related field would be OrderHeaderID and I believe an INNER JOIN would be used. I just can't seem to integrate my case into the example provided on the website...

Comment: @user1305482 Yes, you're right about using `INNER JOIN`. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, Yuck. I'll give that a go and hopefully it will solve my problems! :)